# Excel VBA - Macro that creates new worksheets causes weird malfunction

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a macro that is supposed to add (say 100) new worksheets to my excel workbook. These new worksheets are supposed to be named like this: `1%`, `1.1%`,`1.2%`,`1.3%`,...,`9.9%`,`10%`.

```
Sub AddWorkSheets()
Dim i As Double
For i = 0 To 10 Step 0.1
   Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = i & "%"
Next i
End Sub
```

When I run this code everything works fine at first - it adds new worksheets named as stated above.
But it only works until worksheet `5.9%`. After that worksheet all others get names like `5.99999999`, `6.09999999`,`7.2999999` and so on.
Does anyone have an explanation why that happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This occurs becouse you are using a for-next loop with floating point math, where fractional numbers can't be exactly represented.

[Tons](https://www.google.com/#hl=es-419&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=floating+point+math+site%3astackoverflow.com&oq=floating+point+math+site%3astackoverflow.com&gs_l=hp.3...8170.17173.3.17395.23.23.0.0.0.0.258.4715.0j2j20.22.0...0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.k_YYOsWwU9o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.eWU&fp=5696055428e451b2&biw=1440&bih=752) of explanations here on SO, of why this occurs. Below, a way to correct your code.

```
Sub AddWorkSheets()
Dim i As Double
For i = 0 To 100 Step 1
  Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = round(i/10,1) & "%"
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: And what about `Does anyone have an explanation why that happens?`

Comment: Thanks both Luis Siquot and Peter L. for your help